# Jquery/Javascript Retrieval of URL Not Working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url, gmail

Im trying to get this complete url: 
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2#inbox/13047asdee8be4e1

Through the use of:

```
var url = document.location.toString();
```

But it only returns up to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2

I have also tried other ways like document.url, window.location and it still spits out same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `window.location.href`. Read this: [window.location - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Run this in console to be sure.

```
function showLoc()
{
  var x = window.location;
  var t = ['Property - Typeof - Value',
            'window.location - ' + (typeof x) + ' - ' + x ];
  for (var prop in x){
    t.push(prop + ' - ' + (typeof x[prop]) + ' - ' +  (x[prop] || 'n/a'));
  }
  alert(t.join('\n'));
}
showLoc();
```

Disclaimer: <strike>This is the first time I am seeing all other answers wrong, except Jason :)</strike>  So many good answers. Both describing how to go about solving it in a round about way and then showing the correct way as an afterthought :)

Comment: Sorry I thought it was working the other way but your right you have to follow what you did to produce the correct answer.

Comment: @Novazero: no probs. just wanted to show that this is the correct method :)

Answer (score 6):

Try `window.location.hash` to get the part after the `#`.

You can then get the entire thing with `window.location + '#' + window.location.hash`

You can also get the entire string with `window.location.href`

Answer (score 6):

```
var url = document.location.toString() + '#' + window.location.hash;
```

`document.location.href` seemed to work as well and returned the entire address bar in my test.

Answer (score 3):

`var url = window.location.href;` should do it.

Comment: +1 so that any guys who may check this won't get the wrong impression. this is all you need :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any jQuery for that. You'd simply need to append the hash at the and of your url. Something like this should work.

`var url = document.location.toString() + "#" + window.location.hash;`